# Can I Recreate The Following MySQL Query In CakePHP?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, join, cakephp-1.3

I'm trying to achieve this query in CakePHP (1.3, if that's relevant):

```
select * from releases r join formats f on r.id = f.release_id
    where r.default_upc = f.bar_code
```

I was hoping I could do something in the Release model like:

```
    var $hasOne = array('Format'=>array(
        'conditions' => array('Release.default_upc'=>'Format.bar_code')
    ));
```

Unfortunately this just results in a null Format; evidently 'Format.bar_code' is not yet available at the time the query is made.

What's the quickest route to getting the results I want?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, it does appear that simply changing the conditions to

```
'conditions' => array('Release.default_upc = Format.bar_code')
```

may elicit the results I seek. Is this an idiomatic Cake way of doing things?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, using conditions with JOINS, in cakePHP, should be done as you did in the answer you provided.
Happened to me several times before
The first way should be used in the model itself and within "regular" find calls.

Comment: Yes, I found some examples in the Cookbook that seem to follow this format, so I guess it's A-OK!